# Parse Multiple checkbox value Jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to parse with ajax to php file the following form. I can't use use serialize().

```
< input type="checkbox" name="Filter[0]" value="Train" id="Filter">
< input type="checkbox" name="Filter[1]" value="Airplane" id="Filter1">
```

I was thinking

```
var Filter = $('#Filter').val();
.....
data: {..., ..., Filter:Filter}
```

it doesn't work. Any Idea?

Comment: Is there a _reason_ for not using serialize?

Comment: yes because I have also pagination {page:page, ..., Filter:Filter}

Comment: So just do `form.serialize() + '&page=' + page;`

Comment: It makes sense I will try.

Comment: why do your `name` attributes have indices?

Comment: @LoganMurphy that is allowed. For the post.

Comment: @ Logan Murphy  array foreach

Comment: I would think you would need to select all the "checked" items, then append their values to an array and send that.  You can get the checked ones by doing `$('input:checked')`.  Monkey with the selector to narrow it down as you need too.  This will get you all the checked items, from which you should be able to get their `val()` and do what you need too.

Comment: Excellent and easy. I'm fine with this @ Neal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var filters = $("input[name^='Filter']");
var filterObj = {};
filters.each(function(index){
    filterObj['filter' + index] = this.value;
});
```